Cannot call contract function using ethers.js
I am new to web3 and smart contract development and I am stuck trying to call a function in my smart contract.
I have a mintToken function:
    function mintToken(uint256 tokenId, string memory _type, string memory _breed, uint256 _herdNum) 
    public returns(uint256) {

        NFT storage nft = id2NFT[tokenId];
        nft.id = tokenId;
        nft.animalType = _type;
        nft.breed = _breed;
        nft.herdNumber = _herdNum;
        nft.intervals.push(block.timestamp);

        _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenId);

        emit Mint(msg.sender, tokenId);

        return nft.id;
    }


The full contract is here:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// Compatible with OpenZeppelin Contracts ^5.0.0
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract ProductTracker is ERC721("HalalTrace", "HTrace") {

    address public owner;
    

    event Mint(address minter, uint256 tokenId);
    event Updated(address minter, string newURI);

    /**
     * @dev defines an event which occurs at the major control points of the supply chain
     */
    struct Event {
        address participant;
        string dataURI;
        uint256 timestamp;
    }

    /**
    * @dev defines the basic metadata of each animal NFT.
    */
    struct NFT {
        uint256 id;
        string animalType;
        string breed;
        uint256 herdNumber;
        Event[] trace;
        uint256[] intervals;
    }

    /**
    * @dev maps ids to products
    */
    mapping (uint256 => NFT) private id2NFT;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    /**
     * @dev function to mint animal nft
     * @param tokenId the unique id of the animal on the farm
     * @param _type the type of animal
     * @param _breed the breed of the animal
     * @param _herdNum the herd number of the animal
     */
    function mintToken(uint256 tokenId, string memory _type, string memory _breed, uint256 _herdNum) 
    public returns(uint256) {

        NFT storage nft = id2NFT[tokenId];
        nft.id = tokenId;
        nft.animalType = _type;
        nft.breed = _breed;
        nft.herdNumber = _herdNum;
        nft.intervals.push(block.timestamp);

        _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenId);

        emit Mint(msg.sender, tokenId);

        return nft.id;
    }

    /**
     * @dev function to update the event metadata
     * @param tokenId the unique id of the animal
     * @param dataURI the new uri pointing to IPFS file
     */
    function updateTrace(uint256 tokenId, string memory dataURI) public {
        // ensure only the owner of the NFT can update it
        require(ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender);

        NFT storage nft = id2NFT[tokenId];
        nft.trace.push(Event(msg.sender, dataURI, block.timestamp));

        emit Updated(msg.sender, dataURI);
    }

    /**
    * @dev function to return the details for a given animal product
    */
    function getAnimalDetails(uint256 tokenId) 
        public 
        view 
        returns (
            string memory, 
            string memory, 
            uint256,
            Event[] memory
        ) 
    {
        return (
            id2NFT[tokenId].animalType,
            id2NFT[tokenId].breed,
            id2NFT[tokenId].herdNumber,
            id2NFT[tokenId].trace
        );
    }
}

This function for now does not require the minter to send any ether, hence why it is simply public and not payable.
When deploying using Remix IDE, I can use the UI to call this mint function, passing in the parameters the function requires.
However, when using a node script, I cannot call this function. I keep getting various errors. From my understanding, it has something to do with the gas.
Here's my mintToken.js
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
const contract = require('../../contract/artifacts/contracts/NFTTracker.sol/ProductTracker.json');
const API_KEY = process.env.POLYGON_AMOY_KEY
const ADDRESS = process.env.CONTRACT_ADDRESS
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY

  // provider - Alchemy
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(API_KEY);


  // signer - me
  const signer = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY, provider);


  // contract instance
  const trackerContract = new ethers.Contract(ADDRESS, contract.abi, signer);



async function main() {
    // call a function to see if interaction works
    const owner = await trackerContract.owner()
    console.log(`The owner is ${owner}`)

    // call mint function
    const contractWallet = trackerContract.connect(signer)

    const tx = await contractWallet.mintToken(1, "testing", "testing", 1234)
    await tx.wait()

    console.log(tx)

}

main()

With this line of code:
const tx = await contractWallet.mintToken(1, "testing", "testing", 1234)

I get the following error:
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (error={"reason":"execution reverted","code":"UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT","method":"estimateGas","transaction":{"from":"0x892D8dF4897f7126706946ec58aA2B7BE1F36573","maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f00"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f1e"},"to":"0x16dc429c99945251B959B933f79bf96eE2E7Ec2e","data":"0x92566a690000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006636174746c6500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005616e677573000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","type":2,"accessList":null},"error":{"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":51,\"error\":{\"code\":3,\"message\":\"execution reverted\",\"data\":\"0x73c6ac6e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\"}}","error":{"code":3,"data":"0x73c6ac6e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},"requestBody":"{\"method\":\"eth_estimateGas\",\"params\":[{\"type\":\"0x2\",\"maxFeePerGas\":\"0x59682f1e\",\"maxPriorityFeePerGas\":\"0x59682f00\",\"from\":\"0x892d8df4897f7126706946ec58aa2b7be1f36573\",\"to\":\"0x16dc429c99945251b959b933f79bf96ee2e7ec2e\",\"data\":\"0x92566a690000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006636174746c6500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005616e677573000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\"}],\"id\":51,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}","requestMethod":"POST","url":"https://polygon-amoy.g.alchemy.com/v2/gtILQ7A26pMUgtf-l9QqNMU_PSdUXZ-3"}}, tx={"data":"0x92566a690000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006636174746c6500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005616e677573000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","to":{},"from":"0x892D8dF4897f7126706946ec58aA2B7BE1F36573","type":2,"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f1e"},"maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f00"},"nonce":{},"gasLimit":{},"chainId":{}}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=abstract-signer/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:238:21)
    at Logger.throwError (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:247:20)
    at /home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/abstract-signer/lib/index.js:365:47
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 7) {
  reason: 'cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit',
  code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
  error: Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="execution reverted", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0x892D8dF4897f7126706946ec58aA2B7BE1F36573","maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f00"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f1e"},"to":"0x16dc429c99945251B959B933f79bf96eE2E7Ec2e","data":"0x92566a690000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006636174746c6500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005616e677573000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","type":2,"accessList":null}, error={"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":51,\"error\":{\"code\":3,\"message\":\"execution reverted\",\"data\":\"0x73c6ac6e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\"}}","error":{"code":3,"data":"0x73c6ac6e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},"requestBody":"{\"method\":\"eth_estimateGas\",\"params\":[{\"type\":\"0x2\",\"maxFeePerGas\":\"0x59682f1e\",\"maxPriorityFeePerGas\":\"0x59682f00\",\"from\":\"0x892d8df4897f7126706946ec58aa2b7be1f36573\",\"to\":\"0x16dc429c99945251b959b933f79bf96ee2e7ec2e\",\"data\":\"0x92566a690000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006636174746c6500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005616e677573000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\"}],\"id\":51,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}","requestMethod":"POST","url":"https://polygon-amoy.g.alchemy.com/v2/gtILQ7A26pMUgtf-l9QqNMU_PSdUXZ-3"}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.7.2)
      at Logger.makeError (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:238:21)
      at Logger.throwError (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:247:20)
      at checkError (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:122:20)
      at JsonRpcProvider.<anonymous> (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:751:47)
      at step (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
      at Object.throw (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
      at rejected (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    reason: 'execution reverted',
    code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
    method: 'estimateGas',
    transaction: {
      from: '0x892D8dF4897f7126706946ec58aA2B7BE1F36573',
      maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x59682f00', _isBigNumber: true },
      maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x59682f1e', _isBigNumber: true },
      to: '0x16dc429c99945251B959B933f79bf96eE2E7Ec2e',
      data: '0x92566a690000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006636174746c6500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005616e677573000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      type: 2,
      accessList: null
    },
    error: Error: processing response error (body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":51,\"error\":{\"code\":3,\"message\":\"execution reverted\",\"data\":\"0x73c6ac6e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\"}}", error={"code":3,"data":"0x73c6ac6e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_estimateGas\",\"params\":[{\"type\":\"0x2\",\"maxFeePerGas\":\"0x59682f1e\",\"maxPriorityFeePerGas\":\"0x59682f00\",\"from\":\"0x892d8df4897f7126706946ec58aa2b7be1f36573\",\"to\":\"0x16dc429c99945251b959b933f79bf96ee2e7ec2e\",\"data\":\"0x92566a690000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006636174746c6500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005616e677573000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\"}],\"id\":51,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="https://polygon-amoy.g.alchemy.com/v2/gtILQ7A26pMUgtf-l9QqNMU_PSdUXZ-3", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1)
        at Logger.makeError (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:238:21)
        at Logger.throwError (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:247:20)
        at /home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:313:32
        at step (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:33:23)
        at Object.next (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:14:53)
        at fulfilled (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:5:58)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
      reason: 'processing response error',
      code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
      body: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":51,"error":{"code":3,"message":"execution reverted","data":"0x73c6ac6e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}}',
      error: Error: execution reverted
          at getResult (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:191:21)
          at processJsonFunc (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:356:22)
          at /home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:288:46
          at step (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:33:23)
          at Object.next (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:14:53)
          at fulfilled (/home/ukush/HalalTrace/HalalTrace/server/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:5:58)
          at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
        code: 3,
        data: '0x73c6ac6e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
      },
      requestBody: '{"method":"eth_estimateGas","params":[{"type":"0x2","maxFeePerGas":"0x59682f1e","maxPriorityFeePerGas":"0x59682f00","from":"0x892d8df4897f7126706946ec58aa2b7be1f36573","to":"0x16dc429c99945251b959b933f79bf96ee2e7ec2e","data":"0x92566a690000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006636174746c6500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005616e677573000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}],"id":51,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}',
      requestMethod: 'POST',
      url: 'https://polygon-amoy.g.alchemy.com/v2/gtILQ7A26pMUgtf-l9QqNMU_PSdUXZ-3'
    }
  },
  tx: {
    data: '0x92566a690000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006636174746c6500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005616e677573000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    to: Promise { '0x16dc429c99945251B959B933f79bf96eE2E7Ec2e' },
    from: '0x892D8dF4897f7126706946ec58aA2B7BE1F36573',
    type: 2,
    maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x59682f1e', _isBigNumber: true },
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x59682f00', _isBigNumber: true },
    nonce: Promise { 37 },
    gasLimit: Promise { <rejected> [Circular *1] },
    chainId: Promise { 80002 }
  }
}

After doing some searching on the Ethers docs, I understand I need to manually declare the gas price. So I changed the line to:
    const tx = await contractWallet.mintToken(1, "testing", "testing", 1234, {
      gasPrice: 31000000000,
      gasLimit: 1000000
    })

With this line, the tx.wait() never resolves.
Since my contract function is not payable, I don't need to send any ether to it right?
My contract is deployed to the Polygon Amoy testnet (0x16dc429c99945251B959B933f79bf96eE2E7Ec2e). I have verified that the contract is there.
I don't understand why I can call this mintToken function in RemixIDE and not with my own account. I have 0.3629 MATIC which should be enough to call the function considering the gasPrice is 31000000000 and the limit is only 100000 (I read somewhere that 25,000 is enough).
Unless I am misunderstanding the concept of gas and gas price?
edit: I provided the full contract just incase

Usually, this error message indicates that your transaction is going to fail.
Here's what you can do

Call the same function from RemixIDE/Etherscan after deployment
If the function is working fine make sure to console the parameters before giving a call to the function via JS code.
Alternatively, if the function call from RemixIDE/Etherscan also fails, then there is something wrong with your smart contract most probably.


I've got this working now! There were a number of issues:

I was importing the wrong contract artifact, I think I was importing the one I deployed to polygon mumbai testnet (not sure if that actually makes a difference however)
I didn't have a check in my mint function to ensure the same tokenID was not being used more than once

Once I fixed this, deployed again using hardhat ignition and updated my script to get the new contract artifact and point to the new deployed address, it worked a treat!

I've got this working now! There were a number of issues: 1) I was importing the wrong contract artifact, I think I was importing the one I deployed to polygon mumbai testnet (not sure if that actually makes a difference however) 2) I didn't have a check in my mint function to ensure the same tokenID was not being used more than once Once I fixed this, deployed again using hardhat ignition and updated my script to get the new contract artifact and point to the new deployed address, it worked a treat!
